# Laravel eloquent updateOrCreate very strange behaviour

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an array of arays with some values and I use a loop to either update or insert them into the database.

```
foreach($this->newAccessories as $accessory)
{
  Log::debug($accessory['artnr']);
  Log::debug(Accessory::updateOrCreate(['artnr' => $accessory['artnr']], [
     'title'         =>  $accessory['title'],
     'sec_title'     =>  $accessory['sec_title'],
     'name'          =>  $accessory['name'],
     'supartnr'      =>  $accessory['supplier_artnr']                
  ]));
}
```

This works almost ok. It updates the existing values or creates new ones. It works almost ok because I have a value of the artnr that it gets changed before it gets inserted into the database.

```
[2022-08-10 16:47:51] local.DEBUG: 102577  
[2022-08-10 16:47:51] local.DEBUG: {"id":1769,"artnr":"102577-01",...
```

This is the log output from my code above. Laravel changes 102577 to 102577-01 by itself.  Really I'm almost pulling my hair off.

Some more context:

At some point in the loop, there is a artnr value of 102577-01 but its at the beggining of the loop.

The artnr is a unique field in the database, but not a single row with 102577 exists in it.

EDIT: After some research, I'm almost convinced that this happens because the updateOrCreate method makes a partial match and it updates that row instead, but I can't seem to be able to confirm this from any source. Does anyone got an idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the type of the column. The artnr is a VARCHAR and not an INT.

What I did was to cast the artnr to string and this solved the issue:

```
foreach($this->newAccessories as $accessory)
{
  Accessory::updateOrCreate(['artnr' => (string)$accessory['artnr']], [
     'title'         =>  $accessory['title'],
     'sec_title'     =>  $accessory['sec_title'],
     'name'          =>  $accessory['name'],
     'supartnr'      =>  $accessory['supplier_artnr']                
  ]);
}
```